# Problema na Distribuição de COLUNAS no CSS3

Tags: html5, css3, layout-responsivo

Estou seguindo o tutorial no **w3school**, ele está inserindo os itens, um abaixo do outro e não do lado (inline) !

De acordo com o meu código deveria ficar um do lado do outro:

**CSS**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
    grid-gap: auto;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    padding: 0.5%;
}

.grid-row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}


/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .col-esm-1  {  width: 8.33%;   }
    .col-esm-2  {  width: 16.66%;  }
    .col-esm-3  {  width: 25%;  }
    .col-esm-4  {  width: 33.33%;  }
    .col-esm-5  {  width: 41.66%;  }
    .col-esm-6  {  width: 50%;  }
    .col-esm-7  {  width: 58.33%;  }
    .col-esm-8  {  width: 66.66%;  }
    .col-esm-9  {  width: 75%;  }
    .col-esm-10 {  width: 83.33%;  }
    .col-esm-11 {  width: 91.66%;  }
    .col-esm-12 {  width: 100%;  }
} 

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .col-sm-1   {  width: 8.33%;   }
    .col-sm-2   {  width: 16.66%;  }
    .col-sm-3   {  width: 25%;  }
    .col-sm-4   {  width: 33.33%;  }
    .col-sm-5   {  width: 41.66%;  }
    .col-sm-6   {  width: 50%;  }
    .col-sm-7   {  width: 58.33%;  }
    .col-sm-8   {  width: 66.66%;  }
    .col-sm-9   {  width: 75%;  }
    .col-sm-10  {  width: 83.33%;  }
    .col-sm-11  {  width: 91.66%;  }
    .col-sm-12  {  width: 100%;  }
} 

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .col-md-1   {  width: 8.33%;   }
    .col-md-2   {  width: 16.66%;  }
    .col-md-3   {  width: 25%;  }
    .col-md-4   {  width: 33.33%;  }
    .col-md-5   {  width: 41.66%;  }
    .col-md-6   {  width: 50%;  }
    .col-md-7   {  width: 58.33%;  }
    .col-md-8   {  width: 66.66%;  }
    .col-md-9   {  width: 75%;  }
    .col-md-10  {  width: 83.33%;  }
    .col-md-11  {  width: 91.66%;  }
    .col-md-12  {  width: 100%;  }
} 

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-lg-1   {  width: 8.33%;   }
    .col-lg-2   {  width: 16.66%;  }
    .col-lg-3   {  width: 25%;  }
    .col-lg-4   {  width: 33.33%;  }
    .col-lg-5   {  width: 41.66%;  }
    .col-lg-6   {  width: 50%;  }
    .col-lg-7   {  width: 58.33%;  }
    .col-lg-8   {  width: 66.66%;  }
    .col-lg-9   {  width: 75%;  }
    .col-lg-10  {  width: 83.33%;  }
    .col-lg-11  {  width: 91.66%;  }
    .col-lg-12  {  width: 100%;  }
} 

/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-elg-1  {  width: 8.33%;   }
    .col-elg-2  {  width: 16.66%;  }
    .col-elg-3  {  width: 25%;  }
    .col-elg-4  {  width: 33.33%;  }
    .col-elg-5  {  width: 41.66%;  }
    .col-elg-6  {  width: 50%;  }
    .col-elg-7  {  width: 58.33%;  }
    .col-elg-8  {  width: 66.66%;  }
    .col-elg-9  {  width: 75%;  }
    .col-elg-10 {  width: 83.33%;  }
    .col-elg-11 {  width: 91.66%;  }
    .col-elg-12 {  width: 100%;  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid-system.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-row">

                <div class="col-elg-3" style="background-color: red">1</div>
                <div class="col-elg-3" style="background-color: red">2</div>
                <div class="col-elg-3" style="background-color: red">3</div>
                <div class="col-elg-3" style="background-color: red;">4</div>


        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Cara não sei como é o tutorial, mas parece que ficou faltando vc fazer a classe `.grid-row`

Peguei seu código e apenas adicionei o `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);` que seria 4 colunas de 1fr

Onde vc repete 12x auto: `grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;`

Poderia ser: `grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);` 12 intervalos iguais de 1fr

**OBS 1:** Repare que se vc deletar a div `<div class="grid-row">` o seu Grid vai encaixar no Grid principal, e as divs vão ficar na mesma linha.

**OBS 2:** Se vc colocar `display:flex` na `<div class="grid-row">` também resolve o problema, só usei o `grid-template` pq não sei como vc quer montar o Grid completo então segui usando `dispaly:grid`

Veja como fica o código

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
    grid-gap: auto;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    padding: 0.5%;
}
.grid-row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
.grid-row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .col-esm-1  {  width: 8.33%;   }
    .col-esm-2  {  width: 16.66%;  }
    .col-esm-3  {  width: 25%;  }
    .col-esm-4  {  width: 33.33%;  }
    .col-esm-5  {  width: 41.66%;  }
    .col-esm-6  {  width: 50%;  }
    .col-esm-7  {  width: 58.33%;  }
    .col-esm-8  {  width: 66.66%;  }
    .col-esm-9  {  width: 75%;  }
    .col-esm-10 {  width: 83.33%;  }
    .col-esm-11 {  width: 91.66%;  }
    .col-esm-12 {  width: 100%;  }
} 

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .col-sm-1   {  width: 8.33%;   }
    .col-sm-2   {  width: 16.66%;  }
    .col-sm-3   {  width: 25%;  }
    .col-sm-4   {  width: 33.33%;  }
    .col-sm-5   {  width: 41.66%;  }
    .col-sm-6   {  width: 50%;  }
    .col-sm-7   {  width: 58.33%;  }
    .col-sm-8   {  width: 66.66%;  }
    .col-sm-9   {  width: 75%;  }
    .col-sm-10  {  width: 83.33%;  }
    .col-sm-11  {  width: 91.66%;  }
    .col-sm-12  {  width: 100%;  }
} 

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .col-md-1   {  width: 8.33%;   }
    .col-md-2   {  width: 16.66%;  }
    .col-md-3   {  width: 25%;  }
    .col-md-4   {  width: 33.33%;  }
    .col-md-5   {  width: 41.66%;  }
    .col-md-6   {  width: 50%;  }
    .col-md-7   {  width: 58.33%;  }
    .col-md-8   {  width: 66.66%;  }
    .col-md-9   {  width: 75%;  }
    .col-md-10  {  width: 83.33%;  }
    .col-md-11  {  width: 91.66%;  }
    .col-md-12  {  width: 100%;  }
} 

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-lg-1   {  width: 8.33%;   }
    .col-lg-2   {  width: 16.66%;  }
    .col-lg-3   {  width: 25%;  }
    .col-lg-4   {  width: 33.33%;  }
    .col-lg-5   {  width: 41.66%;  }
    .col-lg-6   {  width: 50%;  }
    .col-lg-7   {  width: 58.33%;  }
    .col-lg-8   {  width: 66.66%;  }
    .col-lg-9   {  width: 75%;  }
    .col-lg-10  {  width: 83.33%;  }
    .col-lg-11  {  width: 91.66%;  }
    .col-lg-12  {  width: 100%;  }
} 

/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-elg-1  {  width: 8.33%;   }
    .col-elg-2  {  width: 16.66%;  }
    .col-elg-3  {  width: 25%;  }
    .col-elg-4  {  width: 33.33%;  }
    .col-elg-5  {  width: 41.66%;  }
    .col-elg-6  {  width: 50%;  }
    .col-elg-7  {  width: 58.33%;  }
    .col-elg-8  {  width: 66.66%;  }
    .col-elg-9  {  width: 75%;  }
    .col-elg-10 {  width: 83.33%;  }
    .col-elg-11 {  width: 91.66%;  }
    .col-elg-12 {  width: 100%;  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-row">

            <div class="col-elg-3" style="background-color: red">1</div>
            <div class="col-elg-3" style="background-color: red">2</div>
            <div class="col-elg-3" style="background-color: red">3</div>
            <div class="col-elg-3" style="background-color: red;">4</div>


    </div>

</div>
```

---

**Imagem no DevTools, repare na linha pontilhada do template dos Grids**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: qual objeto deste código que você adicionou? pois não achei nenhum "repeat" no w3 referente a isto.. E outra, eu fiz da maneira correta?

Comment: @THIAGOSAAD o repeat() significa que vc vai repetir o tamanho do grid, então em vez de vc escrever 12 vez auto, auto, auto... vc pode só escrever repeat(12, 1fr). No caso como vc tinha 4 col-elg-3 eu repeti repeat(4, 1fr). Isso significa que são 4 intervalos de tamanho igual. Mas não sei exatamente o que vc pretende com o grid, da forma que vc montou as divs no html ficou um pouco estranho, pq é um Grid dentro de outro repare na imagem que eu postei que tem um gride de 12 colunas, mas na primeira célula tem outro grid com 4 colunas com os box vermelhos.

Comment: @THIAGOSAAD repare que se vc deletar a div `<div class="grid-row">` o seu Grid vai encaixar no Grid principal, e as divs vão ficar na mesma linha. No Geral eu achei esse CSS meio estenho, parece que está misturando um Grid feito em Flex com um Grid Template. De qq forma espero que a resposta ajude

Comment: então o meu intuito é aprender o funcionamento dos frameworks, o do bootstrap por exemplo. Você tem algum material para eu aprender do jeito correto?

Comment: @THIAGOSAAD vc já está no caminho certo que é ler, testar, errar e corrigir. Eu sou da velha guarda, então eu gosto de ler a documentação das coisas para entender como elas funcionam. Minha dica sobre o Bootstrap é que vc leia e releia a documentação, mas para isso seria interessante saber os fundamentos do CSS. Com isso independente do Framwark vc sempre vai saber o que está fazendo e não só copiando e colando as coisas. Então saber os fundamentos do display:flex vai te ajudar muito a entender o Grid do BS por exemplo. Estude os fundamentos do CSS, no youtube tem MUITO material em ingles e pt

Comment: Muda o nick pra "HugoCSS" rs...

Comment: @dvd é só trocar o L por um S nunca tinha reparado :D. Agora já estou vendo umas aulas de JS, só coisa bem básica mesmo, entendendo o que é var, array, objeto, função etc. Quero terminar o ano respondendo umas questões de JS tb! Vez ou outra fico lendo umas resposta de JS pra ver se já pegando alguma coisa, só que acho que vou ter que estudar lógica de programação tb antes de aprofundar. Valeu a força dvd!

Comment: Isso aí garoto! Torço pelo çuçeçu!